# Problem in rendering site using hugo-xmin theme in blogdown

Tags: hugo, blogdown

I am trying to change the theme of my site to `hugo-xmin`, but I am not able to get the site to render properly. I get the home page I want (below), but then I don't get the `Contact` page (I also don't see it in the `public` directory).

[image]

Also, I don't see my posts in the right format, I see a directory type of listing and I don't see anything in the `categories` or `tags` also.

The Posts page is pasted below

[image]

I get the `404` message for `Contact`, as seen below (perhaps because there is no `contact.html` in the `public` folder).

I have tried to understand the documentation of the theme in the `blogdown` book, but I am not able to make much progress. Any help here would be highly appreciated!

The source code of the site can be found at - https://github.com/sn248/sn248.github.io

I am using `blogdown` version `0.20` and `hugo` version - `0.75.1`, `R` version - `4.0.2` and `rmarkdown` version - `2.3`.

Thanks!

Satya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[I just created a PR on Github](https://github.com/sn248/sn248.github.io/pull/1) to fix your issue. As I mentioned there, `index.md` has a special meaning in Hugo (index file for leaf bundles), and you should use `_index.md` here (i.e., `content/_index.md` instead of `content/index.md`). See https://gohugo.io/content-management/page-bundles/ for more information about bundles in Hugo.

Comment: Thank you very much Yihue! I will also try to update `hugo` on Netlify as per your advice.